# SQL Server Connection string with non-administrator user

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-express

I'm new to SQL in general. I wrote a long time ago a software using ADO libraries in VB.Net but now I'm moving toward pure SQL statements.

I'm trying to figure out a problem in my connection string with non-administrator users. The server has different user according the person that logs-in from the client. Each user has their own privileges and so on.

When a client start the program they connect to the main database on the server using this connection string:

```
Data Source=PC-SERVER\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=dbVarese;Integrated Security=SSPI; User ID=sa;Password=(password);
```

The exception generated from the jit debugger is that it is unable to connect to the database for the user `DOMAIN\Test1`.

As I said before, the problem comes up only when I'm trying to connect using a user that is not flagged as administrator.

Comment: I thought it was "... Integrated Security=true; user....."  for when you specify a windows user and password (as opposed to SQL auth)

Comment: Are you using auto generated SQL connection? Please check your config file whether a SQL Connection defined for windows authentication? It is possible if you auto generated datasets.

Answer (score 1):

Remove username and password form the Connection String, and it will attempt to connect using the Windows Credentials.

```
"data Source=XXXX;Initial Catalog=XXXXXX;Integrated Security=SSPI"
```

In SQL Server be sure that your user is set up for Windows Authentication